# How to import Google App Script projects into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-apps-script, google-api

I searched if there is a way to work on my `Google App Script` projects using `Eclipse` (Eclipse Luna) and I landed on [this page](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/apps_script). But I couldn't follow it to the end because the `Eclipse` dialog that should've shown my projects so I can import what project I want to start working on, was empty and had only a folder icon named `My Drive`. I clicked and double-clicked it, nothing happens.

[image]

So I searched more and found [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export) and when I reached the [authorization section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export#authorization) , I felt totally lost !

The authorization page instructed me to register my application using [this page](https://console.developers.google.com/project) but now I don't know what else should I do to enable `Google App Script` development on `Eclipse` !

So how can I enabled `Google App Script` devlopment on `Eclipse` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Plugin is based on the Google Apps Import/Export API. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export#limitations):

> The API allows access to standalone scripts (the scripts that appear in your Google Drive). Container-bound scripts cannot be accessed through the API.

So if you created an earlier project from with (for example) Google sheets, it will not show up in the import.

To test:

- login to Google and go to [google Script](https://script.google.com).
- Choose: Create a blank project.
- Save the project as (for example) my-project.

The project you created should now show up in the Import wizard.

See also here: developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/apps_script :

> Creating a new project in Eclipse is not supported. You can only import existing projects.
>
> Renaming the project in your workspace does not rename it in the script editor or Google Drive.
>
> All `.gs` and `.html` files that are to be saved back to Google Drive must be in the project's root folder. Other types of files, and files in subfolders of the Eclipse project, are not considered to be part of the Apps Script project on Google Drive.
>
> Autocomplete suggestions are not provided for libraries or advanced Google services.
>
> Autocomplete may not always reflect the methods most recently added to Apps Script. Any code valid in the script editor will still run correctly."